# How to achieve my JSON format to be in certain format?

Tags: java, json

I am expecting my JSON response to be in a certain format.

Here is my Company, LocationInfo looks like

```
public class Company {
   private List<LocationInfo> companies;
   // gettts and setters
}
```

public class LocationInfo {

```
  private String localCompanyID;
  private String localCompanyName;

  // gettts and setters
```

}

My controller looks like below

```
 @GetMapping(value = "/url", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
 public ResponseEntity<LocationInfo> getLocationMaster() {
     ResponseEntity response;
     List<LocationInfo> companies = getAllCompanies();
     // some code goes here
     response = new ResponseEntity<>(localCompanies, HttpStatus.OK);
     return response;
 }
```

This is what I'm getting

```
 [
    {
      "localCompanyID": "33",
      "localCompanyName": "Company-A"
    },
    {
      "localCompanyID": "45",
      "localCompanyName": "Company-B"
    }
 ]
```

I'm expecting response to be as below.

```
{
  "localCompanies": [
   {
     "localCompanyID": "33",
     "localCompanyName": "Company-A"
   },
   {
     "localCompanyID": "45",
     "localCompanyName": "Company-B"
   }
 ]
```

}

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a response DTO class and add your list to it:

```
@AllArgsConstructor(staticName = "of")
class LocalCompaniesResponseDto {
  List<LocationInfo> localCompanies;
}
```

`new ResponseEntity<>(LocalCompaniesResponseDto.of(localCompanies), HttpStatus.OK)`

Comment: Thanks for hint, this is what worked for me                                            
       LocalCompany localCompany = new LocalCompany();
       localCompany.setLocalCompanies(localCompanies);

       response = new ResponseEntity<>(localCompany, HttpStatus.OK);